# When does compiler mark default generated constructor as noexcept?

Tags: c++

It seems like at modern versions of at least some compilers (GCC 5.2 and Visual C++ 2015 Update 1) incorrectly generate `noexcept` default constructors when there are initialized class members:

```
#include <memory>
#include <exception>
#include <iostream>

struct E {};

struct A
{
    A()
    {
        throw E();
    }
};

struct B
{
    A a;
};

struct C
{
    std::shared_ptr<B> b{ std::make_shared<B>() };
        //C() {}  // uncomment to fix
};

int main()
{
    try
    {
        new C;
    }
    catch (const E &)
    {
        std::cout << "Exception caught\n";
    }
    std::cout << "Exiting...\n";
}
```

Running this code causes `std::terminate` to be called (instead of invoking catch block) on GCC 5.2 (C++14 mode) and Visual C++ 2015 Update 1.

Live example:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=16efc34ec173aca7

Uncommenting empty constructor fixes this code for Visual C++, but not for GCC. Clang 3.6 correctly (I suppose?) calls catch block in any case.

Are there any rules in Standard that tell when the default generated constructor must be marked as `noexcept`?

Comment: What happens if you explicitly tell to generate a default constructor (`C() = default;`)?

Comment: Yes, there are rules. Start from [\[except.spec\]/17](http://eel.is/c++draft/except.spec#17) and go up.

Comment: Just saying `=default` does not change anything. I've tried specifiying `C() noexcept(false)=default;` but this generates syntax error

Comment: @T.C. it refers only to special member functions and says nothing about constructors of member variables.

Comment: Perhaps worth keeping in mind is that the rules changed after C++14. The rules linked to by T.C. may or may not be what your particular versions of your compilers implement.

Comment: If (at least some of) those rules are still valid, it looks like for constructor, compiler must form a "set" of all types of exceptions any base class constructors and any member constructors might throw and then decide upon the results. As far as I know VC never supported `throw(type)`, so for them this set is either "empty" for `noexcept` or non-empty. Then does it look like a bug in compiler(s)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going by C++14 here; I don't know if post-C++14 wording changes clarified the situation.

The problem is that the standard's language for generated noexcept specifications in the face of in-class initializers is rather unclear. The standard says for generated member functions in 17p14:

> `f` allows all exceptions if any function it directly invokes allows all exceptions, and `f` has the *exception-specification* `noexcept(true)` if every function it directly invokes allows no exceptions.

However, "directly invokes" is not clearly defined in the standard, and is not obvious when it comes to in-class initializers. Your class `C` invokes `std::make_shared<B>` (which obviously can throw regardless of B's exception specification, as it allocates memory) and the copy constructor of `std::shared_ptr<B>` (which is noexcept) in its initializer, but do those count as "directly invoked", or does only the copy constructor count?

It may well be that this is where the compilers differ in interpretation. Clang appears to count `make_shared`, while the other compilers apparently don't.

Giving `B` a default constructor should change nothing, since that constructor is only called from within `make_shared` and is therefore definitely out of the view of the compiler; if it does change something, there's something seriously wrong.

However, giving `C` an empty, non-defaulted default constructor should most definitely mean that the constructor is not noexcept, and different behavior is definitely a bug.

Comment: _If f is a default constructor or inheriting constructor, the set also contains all members of the sets of potential exceptions of the initialization of non-static data members from brace-or-equal-initializers._ - a quote from DR1351 makes me think that compiler incorrectly produces a `noexcept` default constructor here. Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is a compiler bug that has to do with [*default member initializers*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members#Member_initialization). Note the following workaround fixes GCC:

```
struct C
{
    std::shared_ptr<B> b;
    C() : b{std::make_shared<B>()} {}
};
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/SRJQ88734)</kbd>

**whereas all of this *still* crashes** (note I explicitly used `noexecpt(false)`).

```
struct A
{
    A() noexcept(false)
    {
        throw E();
    }
};

struct B
{
    A a;
    B() noexcept(false) {}
};

struct C
{
    std::shared_ptr<B> b{ std::make_shared<B>() };
    C() noexcept(false) {}
};
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/BYYI98582)</kbd>

even further, keeping the default initializer but overriding it with a specific one, also fixes things:

```
struct C
{
    std::shared_ptr<B> b{ std::make_shared<B>() };
    C() : b(std::make_shared<B>()) {}
};
```

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/JIBZ45922)</kbd>

So it definitely seems to me to be a bug in GCC, at least.